# Timepicker javascript validate one input date to be today or before?

Tags: javascript, django, datepicker, jquery-validate

I want to not accept that the date given be after RIGHT now, Im using django datepicker, I was trying the addmethod but i couldnt get to the success, i have some code:

```js
var fech = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
var a = new Date();
var aho = (d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());

jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterStart", function(value, element, aho) {
  return this.optional(fech) || new Date(fech) < new Date($(aho).val());
}, 'Ingrese una fecha de hoy o antes.');
```

The vars "fech" and "aho" throw me the dates that i want to compare. I have already checked some posts but no one helps me, i cant compare the dates with if, because i want to use the validator

```
$("#miForm").validate({
    errorClass: "claserror",
    validClass: "clasevalida",
    errorElement: 'erele',
    rules: {
        nacimiento: {
            required: true,
            greaterStart: true
          }
      }
  }
```

"nacimiento" is my date input with datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I have already use some datepicker, and sometimes the value is not in the datepicker.. So when you try to use your validator, value is null because your validator cannot read something that doesnt exist.
Have you check if your datepicker can be use with an input or something like that?
Hope it helps!

Comment: i could get my vars with date type, and show them.. but with adding a method to my validator i couldnt solve my problem.. then i try to implement an if, like this one:
    $('#datepicker').datepicker()

    .on("change", function (e) {
 

 var asd = $(this).val();
        var cli = Date.parse(asd);
 var d = new Date();
 
 if(cli>d)
  {
   alert("cumbianena");
    }
 
 });